# Serialize zeep object for unit testing

Tags: zeep

I'd like to test the logic of a program that uses zeep without actually making any external calls. For this, it would be nice to serialize a proper response object, or failing that, be able to construct an object exactly like zeep would.

For example, while I'm online writing tests (`serialize` and `deserialize` are the made up functions that I need):

```py
result = zeep.Client(url).service.getFood()
print(food.Flavor)  # prints "bitter"
open('result', 'w').write(result.serialize())
```

Then later in a unit test run separately

```py
result = zeep.deserialize(open('result').read())
print(food.Flavor) # prints "bitter"
```

What I've tried:

- use `repr(result)` or `str(result)`, but these are native python types and specifically don't support `food.Flavor`, but `food['Flavor']`
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914039/), but I don't really want to mock the whole world, just serialize the response